# Java8 Extract multiple fields from a class object using streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List` of `class` `A` objects with multiple fields including `number1` & `number2` apart from various others.

I want to extract all the unique `number1` & `number2` values from the `List<A>` via java 8 `Stream`s.

The `map` function helps me get only 1 field like below:

```
list.stream().map(A::getNumber1);
```

And after the above code gets executed, there is no way to extract `number2`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can extract both by using `flatMap`:

```
list.stream().flatMap(a -> Stream.of(a.getNumber1(),a.getNumber2())).distinct()...
```